# how can convert json date in filter.js

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

How can i convert json date /Date(1439218800000)/ to something like 11 aug, 2015.
here is my code

```
<script id="template" type="text/html">
   <div class="col-md-2 " >
       <p class="text-center">
           <%= startdate %>
        </p>
    </div>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new Date() function (Javascript):

```
new Date(1439218800000)
```

Output:

```
Mon Aug 10 2015 17:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Comment: where do i need to put this

Comment: can u help me on this